Presidential Rhetoric: Historical Impact on Public Safety and Social Stability
What are some historical examples of US presidents whose rhetoric significantly impacted public safety and social stability, and what evidence supports these impacts? Please provide specific incidents and credible sources that document these effects.

If this were any other Stack, I'd VTC as an extremely broad question that can have hundreds or thousands of different answers, and potentially targets 45 different people across nearly 250 years. It also shows a lack of research, which is paramount to asking a good question, as there are plenty of easily found examples throughout every POTUS administration.

I appreciate your feedback and will accept the answer provided. I want to better manage my expectations as I continue to learn how to use this site effectively. I've also heard that including too much detail in questions can be a bad thing on this site. I will take the time to review the resources you mentioned to improve my question-asking skills. Thank you for your guidance.

Lincoln's anti-slavery rhetoric spurred the secession of the Confederate States and a civil war, an epitome of decreased safety and decreased stability.
The pledges of Lincoln and his anti-slavery party were cited expressly in the declarations of causes of seceding states as a reason for secession. See e.g. a portion of Texas's:

they have elected as president and vice-president of the whole confederacy two men whose chief claims to such high positions are their approval of these long continued wrongs, and their pledges to continue them to the final consummation of these schemes for the ruin of the slave-holding States

